# Angular: login page is not working, Username and password is correct still saying incorrect details?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, mean-stack

I am making a **login page with NodeJS API and Angular**, Nodejs api for login is `localhost:3000/users` Whenever I am **trying to login it says incorrect username and passwo**r**d**, Even my password and email is corrected.

**login.component.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppServiceService } from './../app-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth : AppServiceService, private _router: Router) { }

  public loginuserdata = { email: '', password:'' };
  ngOnInit() {
    var self = this;
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("storageselectedclient") && (localStorage.getItem("storageselectedclient") !="")) {
      window.location.replace(location.origin+"/home");
    } else{
      localStorage.clear();
    }

    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        self.loginuser();
        // Cancel the default action, if needed
        event.preventDefault();
        // Trigger the button element with a click
        // document.getElementsByClassName("loginbtn").click();
      }
    });}


loginuser(){
  this.auth.login(this.loginuserdata)
  .subscribe(
    res=>{
      if(res.code=="204"){
          alert("usename and passsword is incorrect");
      }else{
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)
          localStorage.setItem('email', res.result.replace(/\s/g, "")) 
          this._router.navigate(['/home']);
      }

    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
}

}
```

**HTML**

```
    <form class="contact-form row">
              <div class="form-field col-lg-12">
                 <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="loginuserdata.email" class="input-text js-input" type="text"  placeholder="Email" name="email" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-field col-lg-12 ">

                 <input type="password" id="company" required [(ngModel)]="loginuserdata.password" class="input-text js-input" placeholder="Password" required="" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">


                </div>
              <div class="form-field col-lg-12">
                 <input class="submit-btn w-100"  routerLink="/home/deletearticle"  (click)="loginuser()" value="Submit">
              </div>
```

**app-service.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppSetting } from './appsetting'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppServiceService {
  private SERVERURL = AppSetting.API;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(user){
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.SERVERURL+"users",user);
  }
}
```

**appsetting.ts**

```
export class AppSetting{
public static API='http://localhost:3000/';  
}
```

I have tried **My API call in Postman and it is working fine**

Comment: Can you confirm here in this line of code `loginuser(){
  this.auth.login(this.loginuserdata)
  .subscribe(
    res=>{` here... `this.loginuserdata` and `res` have values or not ?

Comment: how can I find if value coming or not ?

Comment: I mean when you call loginUser() function you are passing `this.loginuserdata` , whats the value of this when you are passing to login method of auth-service

Comment: it woks typo in my code

Comment: And avoid direct accessing DOM in angular, use @ViewChild() or template  reference variable ..

Comment: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/grdtech If you help by supporting here, it will help more people in this pandemic . Thank You.